# Creating files in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to create a shell script that contains a variable with a path on which path we need to create empty .txt files.

I try with:

**

```
path=directory part
touch Test{1..100}.txt
```

**

but this 100 files was create in directory which the script is.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One small comment: `path` might not be a great choice for variable name, given the conflict with `PATH`. **edit:** As @Paul_Pedant points out in the comments, in `zsh` the `path` variable is reserved, being an array of strings holding the directories in $PATH. Some other shells, like `bash`, have no such reservations.

---

You could do something like

```bsh
FILES_HERE=/path/to/dir
touch $FILES_HERE/Test{1..100}.txt
```

If you have a variable number of files you want to make, then you can  make them using `touch` in a `while` loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31365662/3856731

---

It might be useful to have a script that can take an argument, and puts the files there, defaulting to $PWD if the script is called without an argument:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

touch ${1:-.}/Test{1..100}.txt
```

(Explanation of syntax below answer.) Assuming that's saved as `test.sh`, and you have called `chmod +x test.sh`, you can then do:

```bsh
$ ./test.sh
```

to put the 100 empty files in current directory. Or, call with

```bsh
$ ./test.sh ~/Documents
```

to write them into `~/Documents`.

**edit:**
*Explanation of Syntax:* The `${1:-.}` means "replace with the first command line argument to this script (`$1`) or default to `.` (aka `$pwd`) if `$1` is unset or equal to an empty string `''`." When you call an executable script, the arguments you give are automatically enumerated:

```bsh
./script.sh $1 $2 $3 $4...
```

Comment: *nix shell variable names are case sensitive. I use `path` all the time in shell scripts.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I know they're case sensitive. That was purely my opinion on variable names, not a technical objection to using it.

Comment: Fair enough, I was basically reacting to the use of the word "conflict" for something which isn't.

Comment: Question is not flagged as any specific shell. IIRC, `path` is reserved in zsh - it contains the same text as PATH but as an array variable, one directory per element.

Comment: if path and number of empty files are variable.. how can I create that?

Comment: @User231 the first example shows how to specify the path using the `FILES_HERE` variable. To specify the number of empty files using a variable, you could try `touch` in a `while` loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31365662/3856731 . Do those answer your question?